# Pyspark S3 write is taking too long

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a spark application that dumps the processed output to an S3 bucket. The number of partitions of my output dataframe in pyspark is 300. I have column "id" (~250 unique values) which I use to write files with partitionBy. So approximately I get 75K files summing to 11GB.

In my spark application, all stages to write this data to S3 are completed, but moving files from _temp folder are under progress. This is going very slow and as per the current rate, this will take more than a day. What is the root cause here and how to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

Do a repartition by the "id" previously to write, this will reduce the number of files per partition to a single one, increasing the speed of writing.

Comment: This will get data to a single node, right? Might not be a good idea. Instead I reduced number of partitions to number of executors at the time.of write. It works in 2 hrs now. But 1.5 hrs is only to that _temp move operation.

Comment: No, this will put all the data of a single partition on a task, so it will write only a file per partition folder, ~250 files in total. The ammount of files that is writing slows down the writing because it has to open and close so many files, and the size of them is so small that it also affect the jobs that need to read from this file.

Comment: too many files == too much overhead == memory taken away from executors. Repartition by id so that it writes file per partition.